# Is it ok to cross-post questions?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

If my question applies to multiple SE sites (e.g. *EL&U* and *Writers*), is it ok for me to cross-post the same question to these sites, or is that practice frowned upon?

For example, I posted [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16087/please-help-me-improve-this-sentence) on [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com) because it concerns grammatical correctness, but I would find it equally suited on [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com) because it deals with writing style.

Comment: I am so sad that this isn’t cross-posted on meta.writers…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross-posting is strongly discouraged.

However, if you feel a question is relevant to two different communities, *provided you edit and tailor the question to each community*, it can be OK to ask in both places.

It is very important that you actually phrase and structure the question to target it specifically to the community of writers vs. the community of English language wonks.

Comment: "English language wonks," eh? I see what you did there.